# Change Azure DevOps Organization setting through REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've been going through the [Azure DevOps API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-7.0), but I can't seem to find an endpoint for changing organization settings through the REST API.

More specifically, I'm trying to change the Pipeline settings. For a project, [this exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/general-settings/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), but it seems at Organization level it is not possible.

[image]

Am I right this is not feasible through the REST API? Would this be possible via the Azure DevOps CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my investigation, there is no DevOps Rest API in the official document as you said. As a suggestion, you could submit a suggestion ticket to suggest the feature on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion.

However, we can use this API in F12 to change the organization pipeline general settings as a workaround.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview.1
content-type: application/json
request body:
{
  "contributionIds": [
    "ms.vss-build-web.pipelines-org-settings-data-provider"
  ],
  "dataProviderContext": {
    "properties": {
      "badgesArePublic": "true",
      "sourcePage": {
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/_settings/pipelinessettings",
        "routeId": "ms.vss-admin-web.collection-admin-hub-route",
        "routeValues": {
          "adminPivot": "pipelinessettings",
          "controller": "ContributedPage",
          "action": "Execute",
          "serviceHost": "{please check it in F12 when changing settings}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Names of these settings:**

*badgesArePublic:* Disable anonymous access to badges

*enforceSettableVar:* Limit variables that can be set at queue time

*enforceJobAuthScope:* Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines

*enforceJobAuthScopeForReleases:* Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines

*enforceReferencedRepoScopedToken:* Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines

*disableStageChooser:* Disable stage chooser

Comment: Thanks! I was able to configure multiple properties at once using the following request body: `{
    "contributionIds": [
        "ms.vss-build-web.pipelines-org-settings-data-provider"
    ],
    "dataProviderContext": {
        "properties": {
            "enforceReferencedRepoScopedToken": "false",
            "enforceJobAuthScope": "false"
        }
    }
}`. The `sourcePage` property is not required.

Answer (score 1):

API is available now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/general-settings/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I am able to update build general-settings through below api:

curl -u user:password --location --request PATCH 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/generalsettings?api-version=6.0-preview.1' --data '{"enforceReferencedRepoScopedToken":false,"statusBadgesArePrivate":false,"enforceSettableVar":false,"enforceJobAuthScope":false,"enforceJobAuthScopeForReleases":false,"publishPipelineMetadata":false}' --header "Content-type: application/json"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The API endpoint you mentioned is for changing the Project's general settings, not the Organization. It's the same endpoint I have referred to in my initial post (except for the version).

Comment: Yes, General Settings - Update API exist But no version of the API works, in PATCH request the API behaves like in GET request, no modification of the state